# Слишком быстрое перемещение объекта по экрану (SDL2)

Tags: c++, sdl2

Изучая библиотеку SDL по [этому](https://www.lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/26_motion/index.php) примеру столкнулся со следующей проблемой. При однократном нажатии на стрелки точка движется очень быстро, оказываясь на противоположной стороне окошка, хотя скорость пермещения задана 10 пикселей на кадр:

```
//Maximum axis velocity of the dot

static const int DOT_VEL = 10;
```

Проверял тот же код на другом устройстве с той же ОС и версией библиотеки SDL, там работает правильно, т.е. дело не в коде.
**ОС:** Ubuntu 22.04.01 LTS
**Версия SDL:** 2.0.20
С чем может быть связана подобная проблема и как это исправить?

Comment: Потому что кадров в секунду очень много вот он и улетает за пределы экрана.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вынужден согласиться с @ori. Если при частоте кадров 20 вы нажимаете клавишу и удерживаете её 1 секунду, то произойдёт 20 событий (в данном случае перемещения). А если сделаете то же самое при частоте кадров 40, то событий уже будет 40. Это известная проблема уже не один десяток лет и имеется масса информации по её решению. Вводится определённая переменная, которая обновляется каждый кадр или по счётчику. Это дельта времени. Я мог бы Вам написать пример через стандартную библиотеку chrono, но лично я отдаю предпочтение встроенному функционалу библиотеки окон. В SDL2 такой есть. Не вижу смысла переписывать что и так много раз написано.
Прочитайте ответы [тут](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/110825/how-to-calculate-delta-time-with-sdl).

Comment: [Глава](https://www.gameprogrammingpatterns.com/game-loop.html) из одной книги по этой теме.